# How can I donate to Ubuntu without PayPal?

Tags: donation

When I wanted to download Ubuntu 12.10 from ubuntu.com, I was asked to make a donation. However, there is only a PayPal option to make the payment. But I don't use PayPal. Is there any other option to make the payment?

Answer (score 5):

Currently you can only donate to Canonical directly with PayPal. [According](http://www.jonobacon.org/2012/10/09/easier-financial-contributions-to-ubuntu-2/) to Jono Bacon, "other payment mechanisms are currently being explored as we speak."

Another option for you is to donate to the projects behind applications that you often use or would like to support. Simply contact the software developers directly and ask them about it.
Or send a real physical postcard to a developer where you thank him for his work, i am sure many open source developers appreciate some kind words just as much as money.

Comment: "i'm sure open source developers will appreciate some kind words just as much as money." - You're obviously not a software developer. :)

Comment: @SirCharlo There are many people who don't want any money for their projects, one example being [W1HKJ](http://www.w1hkj.com/FldigiSupport.html). But i don't think this is the place to discuss this, i just wanted to offer an alternative when donations (or specific payment menthods) are out of question.

Comment: Agreed. There is, however, a distinct line between 'many open-source developers' and 'open-source developers in general'. If you were to survey all open-source developers, I'm sure the answer to "Would you like money in compensation for your work on projects?" would be far from a unanimous "No". That's all I'm saying.

Comment: any news on this? I am sure there are many non-PayPal oriented donors.

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to actually have a PayPal account in order to donate using PayPal.  You can use your credit/debit card to donate.  After clicking the "Pay with PayPal" button, you'll get another screen.  Click "Pay with your debit or credit card as a PayPal guest."

[image: PayPal Payment Screen]

Now, if you just hate PayPal, and refuse to use it at all, I can't help you there! :)

Comment: Its great. but I do not see there this option anymore :(.
It would be nice, if Ubuntu added more donation options. Paypal is not free anymore...