# Can Ubuntu accept bitcoin donations? It seems to be paypal only right now

Tags: bitcoin, donation

Ubuntu should have alternative methods for donation. Paypal is very good for international donations or an ideal payment service.

Comment: I think that there are various means to transfer Bitcoin to Paypal - e.g. http://bcchanger.com/content/bitcoin-to-paypal - **BUT BE AWARE OF SCAMS**. Also, there is even a Bitcoin forum with similar questions - http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10174/is-it-possible-to-exchange-bitcoins-into-paypal-credit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I donate to Ubuntu without PayPal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202563/how-can-i-donate-to-ubuntu-without-paypal)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to actually have a PayPal account in order to donate using PayPal. You can use your credit/debit card to donate. After clicking the "Pay with PayPal" button, you'll get another screen. Click "Pay with your debit or credit card as a PayPal guest."
here Click "Dont have a Paypal account" option and continue.

Now, if you just hate PayPal, and refuse to use it at all, I can't help you there! :)