# Download donation

Tags: downloads

Something I wanted to ask before but always forgot.
When downloading Ubuntu, the donation page pops-up.
The only way to donate is via paypal.
I do not have a paypal account any-more (closed it after bad experiences).
Please, provide a means to donate by credit card.

Thanks

Comment: see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202563/how-can-i-donate-to-ubuntu-without-paypal

Comment: I would download Ubuntu for free and buy a mug or T-shirt ;)

Comment: As @Rinzwind said, I believe a portion of the proceeds from store purchases ( http://shop.ubuntu.com/ ) goes towards development... Still, you would think that alternative donation methods would be available - I use PayPal, but as this shows, not everyone does.

Comment: @GregoryOpera I agree. I can put money from my CC to paypall but I also relate to defossez sentiment: paypall is not the most user frienly company.